# wildfly 8.2 Read properties files inside ear

Tags: java, properties, wildfly-8

I need to read a properties file located inside an ear. In jboss 5.1 I put the file in the root of the ear and it works, but in wildfly it doesn´t.
In wildfly, I managed to read the property file outside the ear according to this

http://blog.jyore.com/?p=58

But I haven´t found the way to do the same but with the file inside the ear. I´ve tried without success putting the file in the METAINF folder, also tried with the "Class-Path: ." in the manifest...

Please any ideas?? Do I have to put the file in any specific location??

Comment: You can put the file together with classes and then use `Me.class.getResource(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don´t have any classes folder, just a lib folder with the jar archives. Do you mean that putting the properties file in a classes folder should work?

Comment: If you need to access files from one `.war` then yes, just put them in `WEB-INF/classes`, just as compiled Java code. No idea about accessing from multiple `.war`s though.

Comment: No, I don´t have any .war in the .ear, just a few ejb´s deployed. I need to access to the properties from those ejb´s

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

In WildFly 8, to get those properties available in the classpath, package them within your application. For example, if you are deploying a .war then package those properties in WAR WEB-INF/classes/ folder. If you want those properties accessible to all components in a .ear, then package them at the root of some .jar and place that jar in EAR lib/ folder.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly

Thanks for your help